# Framework Unit Test produced the following errors ( library not loaded @rpath.... )

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, frameworks, bundle

We are developing unit tests for a framework that has dependencies on the 3rd party universal framework (3rd party is not Pod Framework, Other Team send to me).

A 3rd party framework is a dynamic framework.

For general framework creation, the build succeeds without any problems.

But only when I run the unit test, I get an error.

**Framework Test Fail Error Log Image**

[image: Framework Test Fail Error Log Image]

I have set the unit test target as follows:

**Unit Test Target Framework Search Path Image**

[image: Unit Test Target Framework Search Path Image]

This is an error that occurs when running a test, not a build error.

How to solve "library not loaded @rpath.... " error.

error log :

```
Assertions: System: Failed to load the test bundle. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/_ /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-fsrbxdcysgbwgthkogsgckulvkkp/Logs/Test/Test-MyTests-2022.11.23_18-41-10-+0900.xcresult. (Underlying Error: ‘MyTests’ 번들을 로드할 수 없습니다. 번들을 다시 설치해보십시오. dlopen(/Users/_ /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-fsrbxdcysgbwgthkogsgckulvkkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyTests.xctest/MyTests, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/IotManagerLib.framework/IotManagerLib
  Referenced from: <5F9B547E-7B4F-3682-AB11-EF171819C804> /Users/_/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-fsrbxdcysgbwgthkogsgckulvkkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyTests.xctest/MyTests ,,,,,,
```

My Test Code :

```
import XCTest
@testable import LgIotService

final class LgIotServiceTests: XCTestCase {

    var systemUnderTest : TestObject!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        systemUnderTest = TestObject()
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func test_hello(){
        let result = systemUnderTest.printHello()
        XCTAssertEqual(result, "Hello Test")
    }

}
```

What I did :

1. I put the Path where the framework exists in Framework Search Paths (Unit Test Target).

What I am expecting :

1. solve "library not loaded @rpath.... " error
2. Unit Test work fine